# Is it bad to use `GroupBy` multiple times in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

This is an educational question.

I have a text file containing several records of power consumption of factories - identified by a unique id -. The file contains the following columns

```
factory_id, city, country, date, consumption
```

where `date` is in the format `mm/YYYY`. I want to compute which countries have less than 20 cities (including those with 0) which experienced a decrease in factories' consumption in two consecutive years. This is nothing but the total yearly consumption of the factories located in that city.

To do this, I used multiple times a `groupBy` + `agg` as follows

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df = df.withColumn("year", F.split("Date", "/")[1])

# compute for each city the yearly consumption
df_consump = df.groupBy("Country", "City", "year").agg(
   F.sum("consumption").alias("consumption")
)


@F.udf(returnType=T.IntegerType())
def had_a_decrease(structs):
   structs = sorted(structs, key=lambda s: s.year)
   # retrieve 0 if list is monotonically growing, 1 otherwise
   cur_cons = pairs[0].consumption
   for struct in structs[1:]:
       cons = struct.consumption
       if cons <= cur_cons:
         return 1
       cur_cons = cons
    
   return 0


df_cons_decrease = df_consump.groupBy("Country", "City").agg(
    # here I collect a list of structs containing (year, consumption)
    # which is needed because collect_list doesn't guarantee the order
    # is respected so I keep the info on the year to sort this (small)
    # list first in the udf "had_a_decrease" defined above.
    # eventually this yields a column with a 1 if we had a decrease, 0 otherwise,
    # which I sum afterwards.
    had_a_decrease(F.collect_list(F.struct("year", "consumption"))).alias("had_decrease")
)

df_cons_decrease.groupBy("Country").agg(
        F.sum("had_decrease").alias("num_cities_with_decrease")
).filter("num_cities_with_decrease < 20")\
.write.csv(outputFolder)
```

however I was wondering:

- is this a bad practice (e.g. inefficient) ?
- are dataframe better suited than RDDs for this ?
- would you recommend a better approach than grouping this many times ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the consumption with the consomption 1 year and 2 year ago by using `Window` and `lag` function without udf and then group by.

```
data = [
    [1, 1, 1, '01/2022', 100],
    [1, 1, 1, '01/2021', 90],
    [1, 1, 1, '01/2020', 80],
    [1, 1, 2, '01/2022', 100],
    [1, 1, 2, '01/2021', 110],
    [1, 1, 2, '01/2020', 120]
]
cols = ['factory_id', 'city', 'country', 'date', 'consumption']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols) \
  .withColumn('year', f.split('date', '/')[1])

w = Window.partitionBy('country', 'city').orderBy('year')

df.groupBy('country', 'city', 'year') \
  .agg(f.sum('consumption').alias('consumption')) \
  .withColumn('consumption-1', f.lag('consumption', 1).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('consumption-2', f.lag('consumption', 2).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('is_decreased', f.expr('if(`consumption` < `consumption-1` and `consumption-1` < `consumption-2`, true, false)')) \
  .filter('is_decreased = true') \
  .select('country', 'city').distinct() \
  .groupBy('country').count() \
  .filter('count < 20') \
  .select('country') \
  .show()

+-------+
|country|
+-------+
|      2|
+-------+
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you find this a better solution ?

Comment: udf is not good in general

Comment: I see, thanks. Then using multiple times a groupBy (or partionBy) + agg is not a bad practice ? I see you did that too

Comment: Depends on the next step but this is good for your purpose I guess.